# GAE Python: Execute simultaneously many independent NDB transactions

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am executing many transactions (100 in fact) using tasklets in NDB. This is the sample code:

```
def import_entities(entities):
    @ndb.tasklet
    def put_single_entity_transaction(entity):

        @ndb.tasklet
        def put_single_entity():
            old_entity = yield Entity.get_by_id_async(entity.key.id())
            if not old_entity:
                yield entity.put_async()
                raise ndb.Return(entity)
            else:
                raise ValueError()

        entity = yield ndb.transaction_async(put_single_entity)
        raise ndb.Return(entity)

    futures = [put_single_entity_transaction(entity) for entity in entities]
    Future.wait_all(futures)
```

This takes about 14 seconds to execute on F2 instance. Can I somehow speed this up? Should I change the approach to a different one? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are the entities all in different entity groups?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yeah. They have no parent entities.

Comment: I believe you're still "paying" a delay for the "transactional" aspect while perhaps not getting benefits (unless there may be duplicates among the entities? or could other `import_entities`-like thingies be running on other instances?).  If you try in an experimental setup to do this non-transactionally, what do you observe -- any integrity issues?  What timing?

Comment: @AlexMartelli the non-transactional approach is way faster (something about 1 second compared to 14 seconds when putting 100 entities). But the same entity could be updated by different requests, so the update must be in a transaction in order to not lose the changes of other updates.